# xarray.dataset.where() does not filter all values

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('./input_file.nc')
ds2 = ds.where(ds.total_precip > 0, drop=True)
print(ds2)
```

This code replaces some zero values with Nan, but i still see many 0 values not getting dropped. If i change the condition to `ds.total_precip == 0` I get a smaller data set with all total_precip values = 0. Am I missing something? Is there another way to filter out from a **data set** based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the wrong logic.
Inside ds.where(condition,other), the condition needs to provide the values where you want to MAINTAIN the original values. In this case, ds.total_precip>0 is maintaining all values >0, and setting all the others to NaN, so any of your zeros is being removed.

If you want to remove zeros, you should use:

```
ds2 = ds.where(ds.total_precip !=0, drop=True)
```

If you want to remove values under or equal to zero:

```
ds2 = ds.where(ds.total_precip > 0, drop=True)
```

If you want to remove values above or equal to zero:

```
ds2 = ds.where(ds.total_precip < 0, drop=True)
```